# Как сделать стены для движущейся точки?

Tags: javascript, html, клавиатура

Делаю квадратик, двигающийся по нажатию клавиш WASD. Как мне сделать так, чтобы квадратик не мог залезать за границу, и, если я нарисую стены внутри самого канваса, чтоб он не мог пройти сквозь них?

```js
window.addEventListener('load',main,false);
function main()
{
  // Задание канваса и переменных
 var ctx = canvas_example.getContext("2d");
 var w = canvas_example.width;
 var h = canvas_example.height;
  
 var fps = 60;
 r = 25; // r - половина длины стороны квадрата.
 ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
 ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
 var x = w/2;
 var y = h/2;
 var v = 50;
 var dt = 0.1;
  
  // Движение по нажатию кнопок
  document.onkeydown = function (event) {
 console.log(event);
  if ((event.key == 's')||(event.key == 'ы')||(event.key == 'S')||(event.key == 'Ы')){
  y = y + v*dt;
  console.log(y);
 }
 if ((event.key == 'd')||(event.key == 'в')||(event.key == 'D')||(event.key == 'В')){
  x = x + v*dt;
 }
 if ((event.key == 'w')||(event.key == 'ц')||(event.key == 'W')||(event.key == 'Ц')){
  y = y - v*dt;
 }
 if ((event.key == 'a')||(event.key == 'ф')||(event.key == 'A')||(event.key == 'Ф')){
  x = x - v*dt;
 }
 }
  
  // Движение квадратика
  function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h); 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, r, r);
  ctx.fill();
 }
 
function control() {
  draw();
 }
 setInterval(control, 1000/fps)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Комментарий -->
<html> <!--Открытие-->
 <head>
  <title>Hello world!</title>
  <script src='alpha.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas_example" width=500 height=500 style='border: 1px solid #000000;'></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А что он должен делать? Останавливаться возле стены?

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/PoodLZM

Comment: Да, скажем, если он дошёл до левого края, он не должен ехать дальше, тобиш, налево при нажатии "A" он не поедет, но при этом сможет поехать при нажатии W S или D.

Comment: Вам уже переписали код на нажатие двойной клавиши, а вы опять со старым

Comment: Доступ интересный к canvas. Просто написал canvas_example и готово. Не стоит привыкать к такому.

Answer (score 3):

Добавил комментариев для понимания:

```js
    window.addEventListener('load',main,false);
    let doc = document.getElementById('canvas_example').getBoundingClientRect(); // получаем координаты canvas
    let xz = doc.x - 5; // Получаем левую сторону 5 это отступ border
    let yz = doc.y - 5; // Получаем верхнюю сторону 5 это отступ border
    let downx = xz + doc.width - 5 - 25; // получаем правую сторону 5 это отступ border 25 это ширина самого квадрата
    let downy = yz + doc.height - 5 - 25; // Получем нижнюю сторону 5 это отступ border 25 это ширина самого квадрата
    function main() {
        // Задание канваса и переменных
        var ctx = canvas_example.getContext("2d");
        var w = canvas_example.width;
        var h = canvas_example.height;

        var fps = 60;
        r = 25; // r - половина длины стороны квадрата.
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        var x = w/2;
        var y = h/2;
        var v = 50;
        var dt = 0.1;

        // Движение по нажатию кнопок
        document.onkeydown = function (event) {
            console.log(event);
            if ((event.key == 's')||(event.key == 'ы')||(event.key == 'S')||(event.key == 'Ы')){
                if (y<downy) {
                    y = y + v * dt;
                }
            }
            if ((event.key == 'd')||(event.key == 'в')||(event.key == 'D')||(event.key == 'В')){
                if(x<downx) {
                    x = x + v * dt;
                }
            }
            if ((event.key == 'w')||(event.key == 'ц')||(event.key == 'W')||(event.key == 'Ц')){
                if(y>yz) {
                    y = y - v * dt;
                }
            }
            if ((event.key == 'a')||(event.key == 'ф')||(event.key == 'A')||(event.key == 'Ф')){
                if(x>xz) {
                    x = x - v * dt;
                }
            }
        };

        // Движение квадратика
        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, r, r);
            ctx.fill();
        }

        function control() {
            draw();
        }
        setInterval(control, 1000/fps)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Комментарий -->
<html> <!--Открытие-->
<head>
    <title>Hello world!</title>
    <script src='alpha.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas_example" width=500 height=500 style='border: 1px solid #000000;'></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```